# Can't run mysql via cygwin after reinstall

Tags: mysql, cygwin

I uninstalled and reinstalled the cygwin mysql base packages ( mysqld, mysql client ) and can no longer access them.  Running the cygwin setup.exe displays them as installed, but the command line doesn't recognize any of the mysql commands.  Where do i go from here?

Comment: No logs, no errors, no details. How can we guess / help?

Comment: Not much in terms of logs.  Cygwin plain doesn't recognize the command.  Not sure how useful this will be but here goes:
$ mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found